# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class <...> with abstract methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, abstract-class, abstract-methods

Here is my code:

```py
from abc import ABC
from abc import abstractmethod

class Mamifiero(ABC):
    """docstring for Mamifiero"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.alimentacion = 'carnivoro'
    
    @abstractmethod
    def __respirar(self):
        print('inhalar... exhalar')
    
class Perro(Mamifiero):
    """docstring for Perro"""
    def __init__(self, ojos=2,):
        self.ojos = ojos
```

I want that `perro.respirar()` prints `'inhalar... exhalar'` but when I want to instantiate a Perro class show me this error. I want to know what is wrong with my script

Comment: What did you *think* making an abstract method and not implementing it was going to do?

Comment: Did you actually read what [`@abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) does?

Comment: An implementation of an abstract method isn't meant to be inherited; rather, it can be called via something like `super().__respirar()` from a non-abstract override.

Answer (score 4):

By definition (read the docs), an abstract call is a class which CANNOT be instantiated until it has any abstract methods not overridden. So as in the Object-Oriented Programming by design.

You have an abstract method `Perro.__respirar()` not overridden, as inherited from the parent class. Or, override it with a method `Perro.__respirar()`, and do something there (maybe even call the parent's method; but not in case it is private with double-underscore, of course).

If you want to instantiate `Perro`, just do not make that method abstract. Make it normal. Because it also has some implementation, which suggests it is a normal base-class'es method, not an abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override **`__respirar()` abstract method** in **`Perro` class** as shown below:

```py
from abc import ABC
from abc import abstractmethod

class Mamifiero(ABC):
    """docstring for Mamifiero"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.alimentacion = 'carnivoro'
    
    @abstractmethod
    def __respirar(self):
        print('inhalar... exhalar')
    
class Perro(Mamifiero):
    """docstring for Perro"""
    def __init__(self, ojos=2,):
        self.ojos = ojos
    
    # You need to override
    def __respirar(self):
        print('Hello')
```